# Указать явно версию php внутри sh скрипта

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, bash, sh

Нужно чтобы внутри скрипта sh использовал отличную версию от нативной

Ниже приведенный код вызывает ошибку версии php

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer
> dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.0.0". You are running 5.6.40.

```
#!/bin/bash/
wp plugin toggle wp-meteor
```

Comment: полный путь то интерпретатора укажите да и дело с концом

Comment: @teran можете, пожалуйста, пример написать

Comment: писать не `php script.php` а условно `/usr/bin/php74 script.php`

Comment: @teran скрипт sh формата, те вызывается ./script.sh

Comment: так пхп то внутри sh там каким образом вызывается?

Comment: @teran wp cli внутри :)

Comment: @ck1e Ну Вы полностью скрипт приведите

Comment: @teran добавил в описание

Comment: WP CLI - это всего лишь [PHAR](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/phar.using.intro.php) архив, который запускается аналогично JAR файлу, используя текущий PHP (Java) в системе. Если он у вас не прописан в путях, то пропишите. Проблема не в WP-CLI, а в том как ваша система настроена. Как только php -v будет выводить нужную вам версию, то и WP-CLI будет с ней запускаться.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это та что по умолчанию?

Comment: если `wp` это ``wp.phar` как выше написано, у которого стоят права на `+x` благодаря чему он запускается, то замените запуск на `/usr/bin/phpX wp.phar ...`

Comment: @teran а как это сделать?)
Пути:, но ничего из это нет (
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli                                                                                                            
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor                                                                                                                          
WP_CLI phar path:       /root

Comment: `which wp` выведет путь к файлу, будет `/path/to/wp`. Теперь `/usr/bin/php74 /path/to/wp plugin toggle wp-meteor`.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем!, и в частности @TotalPusher

Ответ такой:
which wp выведет путь к файлу, будет /path/to/wp. Теперь /usr/bin/php74 /path/to/wp plugin toggle wp-meteor